# Azure Blob Storage 403 Authentication Failed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage to store my application files. I already done it without difficulty for public containers, but I am finding a little trouble making them private.

To access the files in my private containters I am using the following method to retrieve the final url:

```
public static string GetBlobSasUri(string containerLocation, string blobName, string policyName = null)
        {
            string sasBlobToken;

            // Get a reference to a blob within the container.
            // Note that the blob may not exist yet, but a SAS can still be created for it.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.
             ConnectionStrings["AzureConnection"].ConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerLocation);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            if (policyName == null)
            {
                // Create a new access policy and define its constraints.
                // Note that the SharedAccessBlobPolicy class is used both to define the parameters of an ad-hoc SAS, and
                // to construct a shared access policy that is saved to the container's shared access policies.
                SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocSAS = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    // When the start time for the SAS is omitted, the start time is assumed to be the time when the storage service receives the request.
                    // Omitting the start time for a SAS that is effective immediately helps to avoid clock skew.
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
                };

                // Generate the shared access signature on the blob, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
                sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocSAS);

                Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (ad hoc): {0}", sasBlobToken);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate the shared access signature on the blob. In this case, all of the constraints for the
                // shared access signature are specified on the container's stored access policy.
                sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, policyName);

                Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (stored access policy): {0}", sasBlobToken);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
            return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
        }
```

But then when I try to past the final URI in my browser I always get this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:96d18e26-0001-008e-7eb3-c88fcd000000 Time:2017-05-09T11:01:24.9128128Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rcw 2017-05-10T11:01:06Z /blob/mystorage/profiles/317ce29e-86c9-46d8-8579-8cbdaf385971pic.png 2016-05-31
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Any ideia why?

Update: 
Connection string:

```
<add name="AzureConnection" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=5Z+lqPDdRDdlVwSW6kA3iOIb8jUjJkib6A/gAQ8UeqcgPcsW1Do0NbypYsUguTOpb41cO0S0k2wdBEeqvtxaXQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
```

Url generated by Azure Storage Explorer:

```
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/profiles/169ae1c0-3307-401f-b45c-a50fa86cb1c6pic.png?sv=2016-05-31&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2017-05-11T19:19:43Z&st=2017-05-11T09:19:43Z&spr=https&sig=ZpdhWPHZaUwECoorBwWidaresP50jannOx6ECUdd2Vw%3D

sv=2016-05-31
ss=b
srt=sco
sp=r
se=2017-05-11T19:19:43Z
st=2017-05-11T09:19:43Z
spr=https
sig=ZpdhWPHZaUwECoorBwWidaresP50jannOx6ECUdd2Vw%3D
```

Url generated by Code:

```
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/profiles/169ae1c0-3307-401f-b45c-a50fa86cb1c6pic.png?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=JQgK68ycbhyq1xQ%2BQb6UDrUCcy3jwA8FEZVYununZVE%3D&st=2017-05-11T08%3A19%3A47Z&se=2017-05-11T12%3A19%3A47Z&sp=r

sv=2016-05-31
sr=c
sig=JQgK68ycbhyq1xQ%2BQb6UDrUCcy3jwA8FEZVYununZVE%3D
st=2017-05-11T08%3A19%3A47Z
se=2017-05-11T12%3A19%3A47Z
sp=r
```

New update 29/05/2017:

I decided to change my method and try this:

```
    public static string GetBlobSasUri(string containerLocation, string blobName, string policyName = null)
    {
        string sasBlobToken;
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.
         ConnectionStrings["AzureStoreConnection"].ConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerLocation);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        if (policyName == null)
        {
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocSAS = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
                SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-120),
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read

            };

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocSAS);
            Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (ad hoc): {0}", sasBlobToken);
            Console.WriteLine();

            return blob.Uri + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sasBlobToken);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The error change, now I am getting the following error: T**he specified resource does not exist.**

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of blobs in a container?

Comment: no. I am trying to get the url of a blob inside a container.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SAS start time to a few minutes in the past? Sometimes, clock-drift can be the issue. (though I doubt that's it, given the error; looks more like malformed signature / header, based on error)

Comment: @DavidMakogon just tried it, did not work

Comment: Your code looks all right to me. Can you please check if the account key is correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri it is also correct, it is the one I use for uploads

Comment: @GauravMantri I posted my connection string example, do you think I am missing something? It is for read only

Comment: return blob.AbsoluteUri + sasBlobToken;

Comment: Your connection string also looks OK to me. Can you please tell what version of SDK are you using? I will try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @yonisha did not work

Comment: @GauravMantri v8.1.1

Comment: So I created a simple console app and tried your code. Everything worked well for me. I'm able to reproduce the error you're getting if I use incorrect account name/key combination. I would request you to ensure that the account name/key combination is correct.

Comment: Try to create the container using `container.CreateIfNotExists()`. Put this line of code just after `CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerLocation);`. If the account name/key is correct, you should not get any error.

Comment: @GauravMantri tried it did not work. I even generated new keys and nothing same error. Also went to the azure portal and to SAS configuration and generated a SAS example from there and tried to access it. It failed! So it must be a portal problem probably and not a code one.

Comment: Now that you have generated new keys, can you share the connection string with real "old" key values? Please change the account name when you share the connection string.

Comment: @GauravMantri updated the post with that

Comment: I found one more way to reproduce this error :). Can you please check in Azure Portal or using any Storage Explorer that the name of your blob is indeed `317ce29e-86c9-46d8-8579-8cbdaf385971pic.png`?

Comment: @GauravMantri I also thought of that. It is there: 317ce29e-86c9-46d8-8579-8cbdaf385971pic.png
09/05/2017 12:01:03 PM
Blob de blocos
245.36 KiB

Comment: Hmmm....quite weird issue. I'm intrigued but have unfortunately run out of ideas :(.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for the help!

Comment: @GauravMantri one final request, could you please share your final url example to compare with mine?

Comment: Sure thing! Let me do it in a little bit though as I'm away from my computer right now. Also, would you mind sending me an email though contact us page on my blog: GauravMantri.com?

Comment: Can you share the code that uses the blob uri with the SAS?

Comment: @yonisha...He's is simply pasting the blob URL in the browser. No code :)

Comment: I also tested your code and it worked fine on my side. I suggest you generate a SAS URL from Azure Storage Explorer and check whether it is working or not?

Comment: @Amor-MSFT If I use the SAS URL generated from Azure Storage Explorer it works. The URL generated from Azure Storage is different from the one generated by code. I will post both urls in the initial post!

Comment: i added a new update

Answer (score 1):

> The error change, now I am getting the following error: The specified resource does not exist.

The final URL is as following if you encoded the token. It is not a well formatted blob URL with SAS.

```
https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname.jpg%3fsv%3d2016-05-31%26sr%3db%26sig%3dNGZzNbKvnR%252FRCnz1Dsk%252FJrSn8lVdqszyCF8MuLsdo0I%253D%26st%3d2017-05-31T05%253A32%253A00Z%26se%3d2017-05-31T09%253A32%253A00Z%26sp%3dr
```

Here is a method which could generate SAS without using the GetSharedAccessSignature method. Please try it and check whether it can work on your side.

```
private static string GetSharedAccessSignature(
       string accountName,
       string accountkey,
       string blobContainer,
       string blobName,
       DateTimeOffset sharedAccessStartTime,
       DateTimeOffset sharedAccessExpiryTime)
{
    var canonicalNameFormat = $"/blob/{accountName}/{blobContainer}/{blobName}";
    var st = sharedAccessStartTime.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    var se = sharedAccessExpiryTime.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    var sasVersion = "2016-05-31";

    string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}\n{11}\n{12}", new object[]
    {
        "r",
        st,
        se,
        canonicalNameFormat,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        sasVersion,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty
    });

    var sas = GetHash(stringToSign, accountkey);

    var credentials =
        $"?sv={sasVersion}&sr=b&sig={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(sas)}&st={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(st)}&se={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(se)}&sp=r";

    string blobUri = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{blobContainer}/{blobName}";
    return blobUri + credentials;
}

private static string GetHash(string stringToSign, string key)
{
    byte[] keyValue = Convert.FromBase64String(key);

    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyValue))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. It is also not working 

<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:c7419ca6-0001-0002-75c2-de559b000000 Time:2017-06-06T12:44:04.7362370Z
</Message>
</Error>

But the blob exists 

URL: 

https://.....blob.core.windows.net/profiles//1bcf382a-792b-4c53-b0a0-03e82773e15dpic.png?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=G9YlHjBHrvVI%2fzngwNzBWo%2fyVAnXtmN%2fMStQbcgaGMc%3d&st=2017-06-06T10%3a43%3a57Z&se=2017-06-06T14%3a43%3a57Z&sp=r

Comment: BlobNotFound means the blob is not found in the container. Please open your storage account in Azure Storage Explorer and double check whether the blob is exist in the blob container.

Comment: yes, it exists. if I don't make the containers private, I can get them.

Comment: I found a extra '/' in your URL. "/profiles//1bcf382a-792b". Please remove it and test again.

Comment: it was not the problem :(

Comment: @ruizing Did you ever find the issue. I have kind of the same problem now. I can see that the tokens generated by the storage explorer has a longer value in the sig parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to return 'blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasBlobToken'.

Also, it is recommended to set SharedAccessStartTime to (Now - 5m) to overcome clock differences between machines.

Comment: I don't think both of them would matter. I used the code by OP and got the correct URL. Also, I don't believe clock skewness is an issue here. The error message would have been different in that case.